# remove button input from form.elements array javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a form, and I'm grabbing all input elements inside of it and place them into an their keys and values into an object (That works)... However I wan't to filter out the un needed button... How can I remove it/ ignore it?

if I console.log form.elements it returns:

```
[input#first_name.input-text, input#last_name.input-text, input#username.input-text, input#email.input-text, 
button#submit.btn ...]

  const formatData = {};
  const form = document.getElementById('signup');
  console.log(form.elements);

  for (let i = 1; i < myForm.elements.length; i++) {
      // check if button and remove / ignore
      if (form[i] === 'button') { // this doesn't work
          delete form[i];
      }
      const key = form.elements[i].name;
      const value = form.elements[i].value;
      formatData[key] = value;
```

How can I make sure button isn't included? :\  (this is written in jsx syntax)

Comment: try `if (form[i].type === 'button')`

Comment: @DimaGimburg still shows :\

Comment: I feel like `form[i].tagName === 'BUTTON'`should work. `element.type` also works on Chrome, but I can't find this property in the WebAPI docs. Note, that it's capitalised. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName).

Comment: @DimaGimburg if i log .type it returns text, hidden and submit.. I tried submit but it still shows. I think its how i should be deleting it.

Comment: @Kazimieras .type returns  `text, hidden and submit`

Comment: @Modelesq what about the `.tagName` that I suggested?

Comment: you are deleting it in a loop so if you delete with `delete form[i]` you should decrement `i`, try maybe `delete form[i]` and in the end of the loop `i--`

Comment: @Kazimieras no it didn't like that either

Comment: @DimaGimburg would you wanna create an answer as an example?

Comment: first I need to know if you want to remove it from the DOM? or just removing it from `form` array?

Comment: @DimaGimburg i need to loop through all of the inputs. grab the name as key, and value as value. I just don't need the button input in that loop.

Comment: @DimaGimburg from array

Comment: `I just don't need the button input in that loop` then why try to delete it? just ignore it.

Comment: @DimaGimburg yes! i'd love to ignore it. How do i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter `form.elements` by `tagName`.

```
const formatData = {};
const form = document.getElementById('signup');

[].slice.apply( form.elements ) // convert HTMLFormControlsCollection to Array
  .filter(( el ) => el.tagName !== 'BUTTON') // filter out all <button> elements
  .forEach(function ( el ) {
      formatData[ el.name ] = el.value; // add key / value to formatData object
  });
```

OR, if you prefer the `for` loop:

```
const formatData = {};
const form = document.getElementById('signup');

for (let i = 0, n = form.elements.length; i < n; i++) {
  if (form.elements[i].tagName === 'BUTTON') continue;

  formatData[ form.elements[i].name ] = form.elements[i].value;
}
```

Comment: That didn't work either. I just might have to deal with this on the backend

Comment: Actually how can i also filter out hidden inputs with your first example?

Comment: @Modelesq - `Array.reduce` is your friend - provided functionality is more readable, refactors better and can be shared (better code reuse) - see my answer below.

Comment: @Modelesq - When you say filter out hidden inputs, do you mean `<input type="hidden">` elements?

Answer (score 0):

```
 for (let i = 1; i < myForm.elements.length; i++) {
      if (form[i].type !== 'button') { // or as suggested form[i].tagName !== 'BUTTON'
          const key = form.elements[i].name;
          const value = form.elements[i].value;
          formatData[key] = value;
      }
```

and don't you want to loop through all the elements and start the i with 0?

Comment: ah yeah thats a typo on my end. thank you for catching that

Comment: hmm if i run `console.log(form.elements);` it's still in there :\

Answer (score 0):

```
var
    elementCollection = document.forms[document.forms.length -1].elements,
    elementRegistry   = Array.from(

        elementCollection

    ).reduce(function (collector, elm) {
        if (
               (elm.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'button')
            && !collector.regXIgnoreTypes.test(elm.type)
        ) {
          //var key = (elm.id || elm.name);
            var key = elm.name;
            if (key !== '') {

                collector.elementRegistry[key] = elm;
            }
        }
        return collector;
    }, {

      regXIgnoreTypes: (/^(?:button|submit|image|hidden)$/),
      elementRegistry: {}

    }).elementRegistry;

console.log('+++ elementRegistry +++', elementRegistry);
```